# unable to Hit that Action in MVC, once we add [Authorize] Key word on top of controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, jwt

Soon after we add the `[Authorize]` key word on top of that Action of that action is not been called.

Here is the MVC code:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
//[ActionName("GetCoolingScheduleData")]
public MillSchedule GetMillScheduleData(int id)
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    cmd.CommandText = " select * from TBL_MILL_SCHEDULE where id=" + id + "";
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    MillSchedule mvm = null;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        mvm = new MillSchedule();
        mvm.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));

        mvm.rFactor1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1));
        mvm.rFactor2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(2));
        mvm.rFactor3 = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3));
    }
    return mvm;
}
```

I am testing using the API Testing tool POSTMAN,

HTTPPOST:-->http://localhost:51916/api/L2AppApi/GetMillScheduleData/1

```
Token>>>
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InRlc3QiLCJuYmYiOjE1Mzk3Njc2MDYsImV4cCI6MTU0MDM3MjQwNywiaWF0IjoxNTM5NzY3NjE0LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUxOTE2IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MTkxNiJ9.CVS9YsjVo_-PWrHjnZjBiS6ugkWIu0FQBtRYq-fYF0E
```

the Above token is been created Soon after the Login

the Login will Call and Method Like Create Token .

```cs
private string createToken(string username)
{
    //Set issued at date
    DateTime issuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    //set the time when it expires
    DateTime expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7);

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    //create a identity and add claims to the user which we want to log in
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
    });

    const string sec = "401b09eab3c013d4ca54922bb802bec8fd5318192b0a75f201d8b3727429090fb337591abd3e44453b954555b7a0812e1081c39b740293f765eae731f5a65ed1";
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(
        System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sec));
    var signingCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(
        securityKey,
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

    //create the jwt
    var token = (JwtSecurityToken) tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "http://localhost:51916",
        audience: "http://localhost:51916",
        subject: claimsIdentity,
        notBefore: issuedAt,
        expires: expires,
        signingCredentials: signingCredentials);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    return tokenString;
}
```

Comment: the Status :401 Unauthorized

Comment: What authentication method are you using?

Comment: Token biased  authentication